# Canon WFT-E7B II Wireless File Transmitter and Canon 5D Mk III

Tags: canon, wifi

Does the Canon WFT-E7B Mk II Wireless File Transmitter works with the Canon 5D Mk III?

The Canon website cryptically states the Canon WFT-E7B Mk II has "guaranteed compatibility" with the 5D Mk IV, 5DS, 5DS R. But, doesn’t mention the 5D Mk III.  Does this mean the WFT-E7B Mk II is sort of compatible with the 5D Mk III, but not completely?  And, if so, what doesn’t work?

Officially, the original WFT-E7B is the wireless transmitter to use with the 5D Mk III.  But, as I'll be upgrading my 5D Mk III to a Mk IV at some point, I don’t want to drop a ton of money on an accessory that then won't work with the Mk IV.

I've email Canon to ask, but if anyone here has any direct experience, I'd be grateful to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I've not used any Canon Wireless File Transmitter with either my Canon 5D Mark III, 5D Mark IV, or 7D Mark II. I'm also in the United States where the radios use version A of Canon's wireless products to comply with radio frequency emission regulations. The only difference between A, B, C, D, etc. versions of Canon's radio emitting products is the region for which the internal radio is compliant.*

I have read multiple statements in the Q&A and review sections of sellers such as B&H, amazon, Adorama, etc. where other users claim to be using the WFT-E7A (ver 2) with 5D Mark III cameras. From the [Q&A section for B&H's listing](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1081826-REG/canon_5754b009_wft_e7a_wireless_file_transmitter.html/qa) of the Canon WFT-E7A:

[image]

Other than the updated firmware needed for compatibility with newer camera models, it seems to me the only real difference between the first version and the (ver 2) is the inclusion of two additional cables (one long and one short) with an USB 3.0 Micro B connector to allow the WFT to be connected to a 5D Mark IV or other camera (5Ds, 5Ds R, 7D Mark II, for example) with the USB 3.0 Micro B socket. The 5D Mark III has an USB Mini B socket.

Older examples of the WFT-E7 need firmware updates to work with cameras newer than when the specific WFT unit in question was shipped. The firmware may be updated by the end user by attaching the WFT unit to a compatible computer and using the *EOS Utility* application.

The first version of the WFT-7A may be used with newer cameras using other connectors by updating the firmware and using a correct cable, such as the [Canon IFC-150AB II USB Interface Cable for WFT-E7A Wireless Transmitter](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1081817-REG/canon_9133b001_ifc_150ab_ii_usb_interface.html). The notice from Canon regarding updating an older WFT-E7A to work with the 5D Mark IV is at [this link](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/product-advisories/detail/Firmware%20Notice%20Wireless%20File%20Transmitter%20WFT-E7A%20Firmware%20Version%201.3.0). Support for the EOS R was added with the next firmware version [announced here](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/product-advisories/detail/firmware%20notice%20wireless%20file%20transmitter%20wft-e7a%20firmware%20version%201.4.0).

Comment: Thank you Michael C. I've upvoted your answer. I'll await the response from Canon, just incase they have anything to add, before accepting your answer.

Comment: @mooie The last two links in the answer, which are official Canon announcements of firmware updates, make no distinction between the original version of the WFT-7 and the WFT-7 (version 2). There should have been a similar announcement from your Canon regional. In Canon nomenclature a "version" usually refers to different packaging or accessories included with the same basic product. If there are changes to the basic product, they give it a Roman numeral (e.g. EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS was replaced by the EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II or the EOS 1D Mark II was replaced by the EOS 1D Mark IIN).

Comment: In the UK, at least, the product is named "Canon WFT-E7B II Wireless File Transmitter", i.e. with Roman numerals, rather than with "version 2" ( https://store.canon.co.uk/canon-wft-e7b-ii-wireless-file-transmitter/5754B015/). This, of course, is confusing, but the firmware updates you link to are the clinchers: it certainly appears that the earlier model can be updated for the 5D IV (and R). And, that answers my original question.

Comment: Canon customer service did write back. However, it was clear the person who wrote the message had no idea and simply parrotted back the text on the website that I was querying in the first place.  I should have emailed Canon Professional Services instead, I guess.

Comment: @mooie They're all probably reading from the same script. The people answering inquiries are probably also the same.

Comment: @mooie There may be some difference between the "A" and "B" versions of the WFT-E7B and WFT-E7B II that make the original one not able to use the latest firmware. Have you looked at your local Canon regional website to see what the latest firmware version for the WFT-E7B is? Is it the same for the latest firmware version for the WFT-E7B II?

Comment: I didn’t even notice the A and B designators.  Looking in the specifications section of the manual, the A and B refer to the available radio frequencies the device can use.  A is North America; B, Europe.  There's also a C, D and E.  Whether there is different firmware updates for the different regions, I can't say definitively, but it seems likely the updates are universal.

Comment: The last firmware update for the Canon WFT-E7 is Version 1.4.0 released in 20 Sep 2018.  Support for the Canon 5D Mk IV was adding in firmware Version 1.3.0.  So, it would seem unequivocal that the WFT-E7 will work with the Canon 5D Mk IV (and most probably, regardless of region).  I can't find a firmware update specifically for the WFT-E7 II. It seems the firmware updates are applicable to both versions, which suggests there's very little difference, if any.

Comment: @mooie I also think that is likely you (and my answer) are correct, but I was just saying I wouldn't bet the entire farm on it with the different versions for different radio regions out there. There may be other differences between the regulations that define what is allowable in each region besides frequencies used. Though it is a very slim possibility, I felt it needed to be pointed out. Let us know how it works out if you buy one.

Comment: Agreed! I'm looking for a reasonably priced secondhand unit. If one turns up, I'll be sure to report back.